# jQuery find nearest

Tags: jquery, parent, closest

I needed to find the nearest element, relative to another element.
I wanted a generic function not locked to a spesific tree structure.
Maybe it already exists within jQuery and if so please show me!
Here is what I came up with and it works for what I needed:

```
$.fn.nearest = function(s) {
    var o = {};
    var p = $(this).parent();
    while(p.length) {
        if(p.find(s).length) {
            o = p.find(s).first();
            break;
        }
        else {
           p = p.parent();
        }
    }
    return o;
};
```

-Chris

Comment: What is your definition of "nearest"?

Comment: Great!to make it compatible with the standard return types of such jquery functions, we better change the second line from var o = {}; to var o = [];

Comment: Actually, I think `o = $();` would be better for compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [jQuery .closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)?

Comment: Well, I have a site where I have several checkboxes which is actually offers visitors can order. These offers are not unique and may be on several pages. Sometimes they are wraped in different html or labels. I needed to check the 'nearest' checkbox when clicked on a connecting label. Actually I wanted to check all, but only add a data object to one of them. Closest() only goes up the DOM, it will not find elemtents in f.e another td in the same table. Chris